# 0.py file missing in mdipierro/evote project

Tags: web2py

After installing development environment for https://github.com/mdipierro/evote project and loging in to the system for the first time we need to create an account and for that we need to enter an email,after that the application says email was sent successfully but I didn't receive any email related to that.
After that I tried to test E-Vote without email as it's mentioned in the guide,it says to change some lines in 0.py file.But I can't find any file in my installed system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide seems to be outdated. Actually, if you're running E-Vote on localhost the emails are not sent but printed in the console (see [`db.py`](https://github.com/mdipierro/evote/blob/master/models/db.py#L72)). To set up your SMTP server, edit the `[smtp]` entry inside the `private/appconfig.ini` file.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, it clarified the problem